# React Multiple Svg Images for common Base Path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

In React.js I have one components where I need to use multiple svg images for  tag, all svgs are in src > assets > img folder. I have to import each and every image separately in variable and used it.
Can Anyone help me with this if we import base path in variable and add the respective image in  tag by string literal.

[I did this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3KRX.png)

[can we do like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PIvf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try re-export those images from index file.
/src/assets/img/index.js

```
import icon1 from './icon1.svg'

export {
  icon1,
  icon2,
  ...
}
```

And then use it like

```
import {icon1, icon2} from 'src/assets/img'
```

Or even

```
import * as icons from 'src/assets/img'

icons.map(icon => (
  <img src={icon} />
))
```